# Node Setup to Adjust Colour And Distort Material On Object

Tags: texturing, node-editor

I have set up PBR materials of a wooden floor. I'm trying to connect 2 set of nodes, one which can manipulate the texture of the wood ( stretch it, distort it), and the other group which can affect the colour of the wood, ei make it Red, Green, etc etc. I'm confused how to get the noodles set up.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Unless you know exactly what you are doing, I would not recommend using a gradient as a normal map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it up like this. Start with the same texture coordinate (UV) for all of them, but use separate mapping nodes for the sections you want transformed (stretched, etc).

[image: ColorDiff]

If you simply want to mix the original basecolor (of the image) with another color, use a MixRGB node. I often use "multiply", however try different mix settings to find one you like.

[image: ColorMix]

Comment: Thanks always for your node set up and information provided!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The vector output of the mapping node goes into the vector input of the texture. 
The Normal output goes into the normal input of the material.
As I said above, unless you have a proper normal map, I would suggest using a bump node instead, but the colorramp approach might suit certain needs none-the-less.
As for the coloring, you can use a color mix node, set to multiply, screen or mix with a factor < 1.